# Guidelines on out-of-band server management via integrated Lights-out services (iLO, iDRAC etc.)

Tags: firewalls, attack-prevention, server

Several CVEs ([CVE-2012-3271](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2012-3271), [CVE-2011-4158](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2011-4158), and earlier) point out vulnerabilities in remote server administration firmware; what are the guidelines on hardening this extremely useful component of modern data centers, beyond the obvious regular (and urgent) firmware updates, firewalling and setting up audit trails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most important thing: don't put them on the internet :). Make a seperate network or vlan for them.